# SnapManager Restore Wizard Slow

Tags: restore

I don't know if NetApp SnapManager is a niche product.  But the Restore Wizard is very slow, and I was wondering if anyone else had encountered this problem.  I kill the SPID after 15 minutes of waiting.  For DR, we have would to completely avoid the restore wizard, and instead do a clone copy to development, and copy data from there.

The waiting happens on the screen that says "Double-click to select a backup under the database you want to restore."  After double-clicking, that's when the waiting starts.  Looking at the database activity, SnapManager is gathering the database names from each backup in the snapshot. ( RESTORE FILELISTONLY )

The problem is that there are 38 databases listed under the snapshot, with 40 items each, which means it is trying to restore file lists 1,500 times.

The only reason I would use this feature is in an emergency situation, but it's so slow that it won't cut it.

Example:
Under backup "sqlsnap__SQL_09-15-2013_23.36.08__Daily", it looks like this on the right pane:

Database - 1 Admin
Admin 09-15-2013_23.36.08
Admin 09-15-2013_23.56.19
Admin 09-16-2013_00.11.20
Admin 09-16-2013_00.26.15
Admin 09-16-2013_00.41.15
Admin 09-16-2013_00.56.16
...and so on... on to the next database
Database - 38 WHD
WHD 09-15-2013_23.36.08
WHD 09-15-2013_23.56.19
WHD 09-16-2013_00.11.20
WHD 09-16-2013_00.26.15
WHD 09-16-2013_00.41.15
WHD 09-16-2013_00.56.16

For a total of over 1,500 items.

Did we configure something incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

You can kill the task on the SQL Server that is verifying the log files, then you will be able to click Next to get to the next screen in the Wizard.

Just use the query below to find the task running under smsql, and use the kill command to remove the SPID.

The wizard will show a popup error, but will still allow you to continue to the next screen.

Here is a query to help find the SPID to kill:

```
DECLARE @who2 TABLE( 
    [SPID] INT, 
    [Status] VARCHAR(200), 
    [Login] VARCHAR(200), 
    [HostName] VARCHAR(200), 
    [BlkBy] VARCHAR(20), 
    [DBName] VARCHAR(200), 
    [Command] VARCHAR(200), 
    [CPUTime] BIGINT, 
    [DiskIO] BIGINT, 
    [LastBatch] VARCHAR(20), 
    [ProgramName] VARCHAR(200), 
    [SPID2] INT, 
    [RequestID] INT 
) 

INSERT @who2 EXEC sp_who2

select SPID, [Login], HostName, DBName, Command, LastBatch, [@who2].ProgramName from @who2
where [LOGIN] like '%smsql%'
```

Comment: i feel your pain.